# Program shuts down whenever I input data

Tags: c, error-handling

so, I've tried to create a simple program that creates a new file and puts anything that the user types into a newly created file using `fopen()`.

It compiles OK, but when try to actually write something and hit enter the program shuts down with some kind of an error - `Debug Assertion failed,Expression(stream!=null)` - I tried to google this and folks said that it happens when the file is not in the same folder as the .cpp/.c file. However this shouldnt be a problem since I try to create a file right ? Thanks for any tip ;).

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    FILE*out = fopen("improvements.txt", "w");
    // FILE*file = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    char artist[256];
    printf(" What do you wish to add to the new file ?\n");
    scanf("%c", artist);
    fprintf(out, "%c", artist);

    // fclose(file);
    fclose(out);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try using `%s` to read in a string - `%c` is for a single char.

Comment: you need to check whether `fopen` retured NULL or a valid FILE pointer, if NULL then use `perror()` to have an error message printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What that error means is that you are trying to read a `NULL` pointer. Which means your `fopen` failed. This is why **it is always recommended to have error checks after `fopen`** to make sure this doesn't happen.

Try giving full path to the file in fopen

```
  FILE *out = fopen("usr/Desktop/improvements.txt", "w"); // example path .. put a full path like this in your code
```

Also  .. is artist going to be a single character or a string ? .. if a string then your `scanf` is wrong also.

`scanf` reads string with `%s` descriptor not `%c`. Also if the artist string will have spaces .. then `scanf` will fail .. to avoid that try reading the string with `fgets`

Comment: did you try my path .. or did you actually put in a path that applies to your machine

Comment: Im not that dumb... Ofc i put my path - including hard drive (dont worry , I know about the double "\\".

Comment: @user2943016 never intended to call you dumb buddy .. did it work out for you  ... to debug this issue the proper thing to do is check errno when fopen returns NULL.

Answer (score 2):

There are a whole bunch of things about this code that are dubious, starting with the appearance of a bunch of nonstandard, irrelevant, and/or C++ headers in a toy C program, and ending with the `getchar()`-immediately-before-exiting antipattern, but let's focus on the immediate error:

```
FILE*out = fopen("improvements.txt", "w");
```

If, for whatever reason, this operation happens to fail, `fopen` will return a null pointer, which you do not check for. When programming in C you are responsible for checking whether library routines fail. Because you didn't, later `fprintf` crashes the program.

You should add this code immediately after the `fopen` line:

```
if (!out)
{
    perror("improvements.txt");
    return 1;
}
```

That will cause the program to print an error message and quit if the `fopen` fails.  The text of the error message should tell you *why* the `fopen` failed.

Comment: any idea why his fopen is failing though ?

Comment: Thanks for help, the command "perror()" did the trick. Thanks alot EVERYONE !

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to read a string, or a single character?

'%c' is used to read a single character.
If you need to read in a string, you should use '%s'.

Comment: This is not the OP's immediate problem but it is very likely to be their *next* problem. +1.